# how to store ArrayList Values if programe crashes?

Tags: java, list, crash

I am running a 4*4 maze all possible solution finding programme.
I have set up a method that takes a random combination Value of"R, G, B, Y" as aStrin and checks if the given String is a valid solution or not. for instance, the given String is "RGGGBYYBBGYBGRR".

```
new Thread(() -> {
       //List<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
       String[] letters = {"R","G","B","Y"};
       int done = 0;
       Cell start = MazeBuilder.mazeFor(REPO_NAME);
       while (done != 1) {
           String str = "";
           int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, 48);
           //done = check(temp1, letters, done, start, str, r);
           for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
               Random rnd = new Random();
               int index = rnd.nextInt(letters.length);
               str += letters[index];
           }

               if (Helper.isValidSolution(start, str)) {
                  done = 1;
                   try {
                       FileWriter FW = new FileWriter("ansGrid.txt");
                       FW.write(str);
                       FW.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }

       }
   }).start();
```

so my question is... if the programme crashes or it runs out of memory, how can I store the values of the temp1 variable in a file?

Comment: Yes i want to Store data of List<String> to file.... but only if my program crashes or run out of memory.

Comment: as you can see i am writing generated Strings to file through ``Filewriter``